# Class from external library not found in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I cloned the repository of the [PagerSlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) and compiled it in Android Studio. That generated an `library-1.0.1.aar` file that I added in the `apps/libs` folder of another app. I added the library to the `app/build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/library-1.0.1.aar'])
    ...
}
```

but when I try to import a class from the library:

```
import com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip;
```

it does not find it. I get:

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'astuetz'
```

I resync the app, rebuild, restart... but the library never seems to be found. What can be wrong?

Comment: I'm not aware that AAR files can be included via `compile files()`. If the library is another module within the project, reference it that way. Otherwise, you may need the AAR to be put in a local Maven repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by Commonsware I had to create a local Maven repository (I used `app/aars`):

In `app/build.gradle`:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'aars'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.astuetz:library:1.0.1@aar'
    ...
}
```

Comment: how can i get library version, 1.0.1 in your code ? and give me suggestion about AAR ?